# Test whether event is published from handler

Tags: nunit, nservicebus

Can I get sample of how to test whether event is published from given handler or not.

```
           var cmd = new Catalogue()
            {
                CatalogueCode = "",
                CatalogueType = "",
                CustomerSegmentCode = "",
                DisplayName = "",
                EffectiveDate = null,
                Products = null
            };
            Test.Handler(bus => new CatalogueAddedCommandHandler(bus))
                .ExpectPublish<ICatalogue>(e => e.CatalogueCode == cmd.CatalogueCode).OnMessage(cmd);
```

When I debug the test case it shows exception Interface not found at Test.Handler.

Comment: can you share the message handler code with us?

Comment: Do you want to test if the event was published in general? Or specifically from one handler?

Comment: Need to check whether it is published from one handler or not

Comment: @eraj can you please share your message handler code with us in order to help you with your issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to call `Test.Initialize();`

You can find the documentation on [the Particular docs website](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/testing/)

UPDATE:

```
 using NServiceBus;
    using NServiceBus.Testing;
    using NUnit.Framework;

    [TestFixture]
    public class Tests
    {

        [Test]
        public void Run()
        {
            Test.Initialize(c => c.Conventions().DefiningEventsAs(t => t == typeof (ICatalogue)));

            var cmd = new Catalogue()
            {
                CatalogueCode = "TEST"
            };
            Test.Handler<CatalogueAddedCommandHandler>()
                .ExpectPublish<ICatalogue>(e => e.CatalogueCode == cmd.CatalogueCode)
                .OnMessage(cmd);

        }
    }

    public interface ICatalogue
    {
        string CatalogueCode { get; set; }
    }

    public class Catalogue
    {
        public string CatalogueCode { get; set; }
    }

    public class CatalogueEvent : ICatalogue
    {
        public string CatalogueCode { get; set; }
    }

    public class CatalogueAddedCommandHandler : IHandleMessages<Catalogue>
    {
        public IBus Bus { get; set; }

        public void Handle(Catalogue message)
        {
            Bus.Publish<ICatalogue>(e => e.CatalogueCode = message.CatalogueCode);
        }
    }
```

Does this help?

Comment: I tried with Test.Initialize() method but not worked for me. I want to check Publishing of message not reply.